# Siri speech as UNUserNotification(UILocalNotification) sound

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, avspeechsynthesizer, unusernotificationcenter

How can I make Siri speak UNUserNotification body text on receiving the notification instead of notification sound?

1) Is there anyway where I can detect notification is received and convert the text obtained in notification body to text via AVSpeechSynthesizer?

2) Is there anyway where I can save the speech into an .aiff audio file and assign it to the UNUserNotification sound?